# android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence) on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, textview

Tengo un error muy extraño en android (api 25), ya intente muchas cosas y aun no lo logró, ayuda!! por favor
Intento que la aplicación, tipo calculadora para hacer cálculos de pagos, en la que seleccionas año, meses y situación, y con estos parámetros te calcula tu pago que parece en un TextView, pero me sale este extraño error "Attempt to invoke virtual method void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence) on a null object reference"
El código es el siguiente, es de un fragment:

```
public class FragmentCalculadora extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


    Spinner Sptarifa, SpSituacion, SpMeses;
    Button calcular;

    ArrayList<String> datos = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> datos2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> datos3 = new ArrayList<String>();

    float cf, tar, infra, rec;
    int descue;
    float n1, n2, n3, n4, n5;


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.btnCalcular:

                TextView cfija = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtCFCalculadora);
                TextView tarifa = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTarifaCalculadora);
                TextView inf = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtInfraCalculadora);
                TextView recargo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtRecargoCalculadora);
                TextView total = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTotalCalculadora);


                 System.out.println(n1); //tenia esto para ver si realmente estaba calculando los datos, que si lo hacia

                try {

                        System.out.println("Aqui genera el error");

                        cfija.setText(String.valueOf(n1));
                        tarifa.setText(String.valueOf(n2));
                        inf.setText(String.valueOf(n3));
                        recargo.setText(String.valueOf(n4));
                        total.setText(String.valueOf(n5));


                }catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "hey onclick! " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        int idT = 0;
        String situa = SpSituacion.getSelectedItem().toString();
        System.out.println(situa);

        String tari = Sptarifa.getSelectedItem().toString();
        System.out.println(tari);

        String mes = SpMeses.getSelectedItem().toString();
        System.out.println(mes);


        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection connection;
        String url;
        //mi conexion a una bd
        try
        {

            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SERVIDOR;databaseName=BdCalculadora;user=sa;password=1234"; 
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            Statement estatuto = connection.createStatement();


            //cargar la situacion
            String query ="SELECT * FROM Situacion WHERE descripcion = '" + situa + "'";
            ResultSet resultado = estatuto.executeQuery(query);
            if (resultado.next())
            {
                descue = resultado.getInt("descuento");
                idT = resultado.getInt("idSituacion");
            }
            resultado.close();


            //cargar la tarifas
            String query2 ="SELECT * FROM Tarifas WHERE año = " + tari;
            ResultSet resultado2 = estatuto.executeQuery(query2);
            if (resultado2.next())
            {
                cf = resultado2.getFloat("cf");
                tar = resultado2.getFloat("tar");
                infra = resultado2.getFloat("infra");
                rec = resultado2.getFloat("recargos");

                n1= (cf / 12) *  Integer.parseInt(mes);
                n2 = (tar / 12) *  Integer.parseInt(mes);
                n3 = (infra / 12) *  Integer.parseInt(mes);
                n4 = (rec / 12) *  Integer.parseInt(mes);

            }
            resultado2.close();

            float n = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4;


            if (idT != 6)
            {
                n5 = (n * descue) / 100;
            }
            else {
                n5 = n;
            }
            System.out.println(n5 + " total");


            connection.close();

        }catch (SQLException E){
            E.printStackTrace();
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }


    //omiti los métodos que son creados por android 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_calculadora, container, false);

        SpMeses = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinnerMes);
        SpSituacion = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinnerSituacion);
        Sptarifa = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinnerTarifa);
        calcular = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnCalcular);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection connection;
        String url;

        try
        {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SERVIDOR;databaseName=BdCalculadora;user=sa;password=1234";
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            Statement estatuto = connection.createStatement();


            //cargar la situacion
            String query ="SELECT * FROM Situacion";
            ResultSet resultado = estatuto.executeQuery(query);
            while (resultado.next())
            {
                String descripcion = resultado.getString("descripcion");
                datos.add(descripcion);
            }
            resultado.close();

            //cargar la tarifas
            String query2 ="SELECT * FROM Tarifas";
            ResultSet resultado2 = estatuto.executeQuery(query2);
            while (resultado2.next())
            {
                String fech = resultado2.getString("año");
                datos2.add(fech);
            }
            resultado2.close();

            for (int x=1; x<=12; x++)
            {
                datos3.add(String.valueOf(x));
            }


            //spinner situacion
            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, datos);
            SpSituacion.setAdapter(adapter);

            //spinner tarifas
            ArrayAdapter adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, datos2);
            Sptarifa.setAdapter(adapter2);

            //spinner meses
            ArrayAdapter adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, datos3);
            SpMeses.setAdapter(adapter3);

            connection.close();

        }catch (SQLException E)
        {
            E.printStackTrace();
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SpSituacion.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        SpMeses.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        Sptarifa.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        calcular.setOnClickListener(this);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: El view con el que estas referenciando los TextViews no es el root que contiene dichas referencias, sino la vista que dispara el evento Click. Intenta referenciarlos en el OnCreateView tal como indica la respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba esto. Si tienes un Fragment, dicho Fragment tendrá un método onCreateView que es donde tienes que "identificar" los TextView y crearlos como variables globales.

```
public class FragmentCalculadora extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


Spinner Sptarifa, SpSituacion, SpMeses;
Button calcular;

ArrayList<String> datos = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> datos2 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> datos3 = new ArrayList<String>();

float cf, tar, infra, rec;
int descue;
float n1, n2, n3, n4, n5;

//Declaramos aquí los TextView
TextView cfija;
TextView tarifa;
TextView inf;
TextView recargo;
TextView total;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.btnCalcular:




             System.out.println(n1); //tenia esto para ver si realmente estaba calculando los datos, que si lo hacia

            try {

                    System.out.println("Aqui genera el error");

                    cfija.setText(String.valueOf(n1));
                    tarifa.setText(String.valueOf(n2));
                    inf.setText(String.valueOf(n3));
                    recargo.setText(String.valueOf(n4));
                    total.setText(String.valueOf(n5));


            }catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "hey onclick! " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            break;
    }
}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    int idT = 0;
    String situa = SpSituacion.getSelectedItem().toString();
    System.out.println(situa);

    String tari = Sptarifa.getSelectedItem().toString();
    System.out.println(tari);

    String mes = SpMeses.getSelectedItem().toString();
    System.out.println(mes);


    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection connection;
    String url;
    //mi conexion a una bd
    try
    {

        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SERVIDOR;databaseName=BdCalculadora;user=sa;password=1234"; 
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        Statement estatuto = connection.createStatement();


        //cargar la situacion
        String query ="SELECT * FROM Situacion WHERE descripcion = '" + situa + "'";
        ResultSet resultado = estatuto.executeQuery(query);
        if (resultado.next())
        {
            descue = resultado.getInt("descuento");
            idT = resultado.getInt("idSituacion");
        }
        resultado.close();


        //cargar la tarifas
        String query2 ="SELECT * FROM Tarifas WHERE año = " + tari;
        ResultSet resultado2 = estatuto.executeQuery(query2);
        if (resultado2.next())
        {
            cf = resultado2.getFloat("cf");
            tar = resultado2.getFloat("tar");
            infra = resultado2.getFloat("infra");
            rec = resultado2.getFloat("recargos");

            n1= (cf / 12) *  Integer.parseInt(mes);
            n2 = (tar / 12) *  Integer.parseInt(mes);
            n3 = (infra / 12) *  Integer.parseInt(mes);
            n4 = (rec / 12) *  Integer.parseInt(mes);

        }
        resultado2.close();

        float n = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4;


        if (idT != 6)
        {
            n5 = (n * descue) / 100;
        }
        else {
            n5 = n;
        }
        System.out.println(n5 + " total");


        connection.close();

    }catch (SQLException E){
        E.printStackTrace();
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}


//omiti los métodos que son creados por android 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_calculadora, container, false);

    SpMeses = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinnerMes);
    SpSituacion = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinnerSituacion);
    Sptarifa = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinnerTarifa);
    calcular = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnCalcular);

    //Instanciamos los objetos de los TextView
    cfija = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtCFCalculadora);
    tarifa = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTarifaCalculadora);
    inf = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtInfraCalculadora);
    recargo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtRecargoCalculadora);
    total = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTotalCalculadora);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection connection;
    String url;

    try
    {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SERVIDOR;databaseName=BdCalculadora;user=sa;password=1234";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        Statement estatuto = connection.createStatement();


        //cargar la situacion
        String query ="SELECT * FROM Situacion";
        ResultSet resultado = estatuto.executeQuery(query);
        while (resultado.next())
        {
            String descripcion = resultado.getString("descripcion");
            datos.add(descripcion);
        }
        resultado.close();

        //cargar la tarifas
        String query2 ="SELECT * FROM Tarifas";
        ResultSet resultado2 = estatuto.executeQuery(query2);
        while (resultado2.next())
        {
            String fech = resultado2.getString("año");
            datos2.add(fech);
        }
        resultado2.close();

        for (int x=1; x<=12; x++)
        {
            datos3.add(String.valueOf(x));
        }


        //spinner situacion
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, datos);
        SpSituacion.setAdapter(adapter);

        //spinner tarifas
        ArrayAdapter adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, datos2);
        Sptarifa.setAdapter(adapter2);

        //spinner meses
        ArrayAdapter adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, datos3);
        SpMeses.setAdapter(adapter3);

        connection.close();

    }catch (SQLException E)
    {
        E.printStackTrace();
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SpSituacion.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    SpMeses.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    Sptarifa.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    calcular.setOnClickListener(this);

    return v;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu error es que estas intentando referenciar tus TextViews con el view incorrecto. En un fragment estos deben ser referenciados dentro de alguno de los siguientes metodos

```
onCreateView()
onActivityCreated()


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    TextView textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView);


    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);


}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    TextView textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView);

}
```

Te recomiendo revisar el [ciclo de vida de un Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)